# Sorting a variable-length record, blocked, dataset

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

I have tried to sort a VB file.

File data is:
00000000002 AAA
00000000001
00000000003 BBB
00000000004 CCC
00000000005

The JCL I am using for sorting is below:

```
//STEP1  EXEC PGM=SORT                                       
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*                                        
//SYSUDUMP DD  SYSOUT=*                                        
//SORTWK01 DD  UNIT=SYSTF,SPACE=(01000,(006980,001425),,,ROUND)
//SYSIN    DD  *                                               
 SORT FIELDS=(17,3,CH,A)                                       
/*                                                             
//SORTIN   DD  DSN=TEST.INPUT.FILE1,                            
//             DISP=SHR                                        
//SORTOUT  DD  DSN=TEST.OUTPUT.FILE2,                            
//             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                        
//             DCB=(RECFM=VB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=0),              
//             UNIT=SYSSF,                                     
//             SPACE=(CYL,(5,5),RLSE)
```

This JCL fails with VB file, but works fine with FB file. However, if I add following sort card, it works fine with VB file as well.

```
 SORT FIELDS=(17,3,CH,A) 
 OPTION VLSHRT
```

I am trying to find the reason, why this works for FB, but not for VB.

Answer (score 1):

For an FB dataset, all records are the same length (same as the LRECL of the dataset).

For a VB dataset, any record can be a theoretical one through (LRECL-4). Realistically, the shortest record depends on the context of the data in the dataset, the longest record possible should be the same as the LRECL.

What this means for SORT is that any given field which is referenced for a record in a VB dataset may or may not be there, but the won't actually be known until run-time.

Ideally, if you are SORTing the data, you'd expect on the control-fields specified to exist for all records. However, sometimes there is a different requirement.

What DFSORT does with short variable-length records ("short" in this case means ending before the control-fields specified) is controlled by the parameters VLSCMP and VLSHRT.

VLSCMP is used to control the behaviour for short records with INCLUDE/OMIT statement.

VLSHRT is described thus is the *DFSORT Application Programming Guide*:

> Temporarily overrides the VLSHRT installation option, which specifies whether
>   DFSORT is to continue processing if a "short" variable-length SORT/MERGE
>   control field, INCLUDE/OMIT compare field, or SUM summary field is found.
>   For more information, see the discussion of the VLSHRT and NOVLSHRT
>   options in “OPTION Control Statement” on page 173.
>
> VLSHRT
>
> specifies that DFSORT continues processing if a short control field or
>   compare field is found.
>
> NOVLSHRT
>
> specifies that DFSORT terminates if a short control field or compare

Also note, you can't use the same start location if your data is on a VB dataset. On a variable-length record, the data starts at position five, because the first four bytes are occupied by the *Record Descriptor Word (RDW)* (in this context Word just means four bytes). So for a variable-length record you need to add four to all the start-positions for all your fields.
field is found.

This also means that when you specify an LRECL of 80 for a VB, as in your example, each record can only actually contain a maximum of 76 bytes of data (76 + length of RDW = 80).

Also note that it is not a good thing to put the LRECL and RECFM on the output dataset from EXEC PGM=SORT or EXEC PGM=ICETOOL. SORT/ICETOOL will specfiy the LRECL and RECFM accurately. If you have them also in the JCL you have a second place to maintain them.

Answer (score 1):

Bill is correct, but I will try and give a simpler answer.
In the example given, you have 2 records:

```
   00000000001
and
   00000000005
```

That do not have a sort key. When you copy them to a fixed width file, they get padded out with spaces (x'40') or hex-zero's (depending on how you copy the file). The records now have a sort key of spaces (or Hex zero's) i.e they become

```
   00000000001____
   00000000005____    where _ represents a space (x'40') or Hex zero (x'00')
```

The FB sort will now work, while the VB sort will fail because there are records without a sort key.

The **VLSHRT** parameter tells the sort program to treat missing sort keys as Hex-Zeros and the sort will now work.

---

Have look at bill's answer it has quite a bit of useful information on FB and VB files.